# How can I force redirect back to Facebook page tab if user views outside of Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

There's something wrong with my page tab - I got a Facebook notification that someone commented in the comment box on my page tab, StackOverflow clicked on the link and I was taken to the page on my site directly:

Here's the url that took me there:

http://sehabitat.com/Facebook/index.PHP?Facebook_comment_id=Facebookc_10150365133961604_19446706_10150373950271604&ref=notif&notif_t=open_graph_comment#f27DB40044

How can I fix this, StackOverflow that the url the user clicks in their Facebook notification will take them here instead: http://www.Facebook.com/SEHabitat?sk=app_175821802509443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel Tsyganok's answer is a server side solution and is good and tamper-proof.

However, if you have people behind proxies that strip the HTTP referer field, a less secure way is to use JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (self==top)
        location = "//www.facebook.com/SEHabitat?sk=app_175821802509443";
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the user is viewing the page directly, you will see a GET request.

If they're viewing the tab through Facebook, your page will be loaded with a POST (with some parameters "signed" by Facebook using your app secret, but tricking this redirect probably isn't a security issue, so you don't have to care about that).

Answer (score 1):

You can check where the user got redirected from and if he did not got redirected from the facebook tab (url starting with static.facebook if i remember correctly) you redirect him to the page. something like this:

```
  $ref=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  if ($ref != "static.facebook...") {
      Header ('Location: http://www.facebook.com/SEHabitat?sk=app_175821802509443');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a mix of server and client side scripts to achieve what you have asked for. Assuming php as your server side language, something like below should work in most of the cases:

```
<?php
$app_id = "<your app id>";
$page_url = "<your page url>";
// if your app requires extended permissions
$app_scope = "user_interests,publish_actions,publish_stream"; //etc.

// depending on your requirement you may use the oauth authentication
// or you may simply redirect to your page url instead
$auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($page_url)
        . "&scope=" . $app_scope;

// this is passed only when your page is pulled by facebook
if (!isset($_REQUEST["signed_request"])) {
    // we are sure that the page is not accessed within facebook
    // so we may redirect
    header ('Location: ' . $auth_url); // or $page_url
    die();
}

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

// we can check this and redirect later
$user_id = $data["user_id"];

// other details are also avialable
$user = $data["user"];
$algorithm = $data["algorithm"];
$issued_at = $data["issued_at"];
$oauth_token = $data["oauth_token"];
$expires = $data["expires"];

// passed only when the app is loaded inside a page tab
// can be checked for and if empty we can redirect
$app_data = $data["app_data"];

// signed_request algorithm's signature verification
// is omitted here for simplicity sake. you may perform
// that to ensure the authenticity of the request

// other initial setups
?>
```

Now you may put the below script inside the **`<head> </head>`** tag on your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php if (empty($user_id)): // or as may the need be, you may want to check $app_data instead ?>
        top.location.href="<?php echo $auth_url; // or you may want to use $page_url instead ?>";
</script>
```